# Android - Connect() / Socket(ip, port) does NOTHING

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets

**EDIT: I've managed to connect the server from a python client, which means that there's a problem in the ANDROID connection. I've been trying to figure it out in the last 2 hours- the connect() function nor the socket() function, does nothing! I'm freaking out.**

**PROBLEM:** ,
I'm working on an android application, which basically communicates with a server that runs on my laptop in c++ (my laptop OS is Windows 8).

My client connects to the server only when I'm connected to my home network. When I'm connected to other networks, my client throws an exception:

** The server computer connected with a cable **

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.60 (port 5898) after 3000ms
```

**The Android code:**

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

       Socket client_socket = new Socket(); // Creates a socket and binds it to available port.
       Log.d("INFO", "Created Socket");

       for (int retries = 0; retries < 3; retries++) {
          try {
              client_socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 5898), 3000); // Connect to the server.
              break;
          } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
              Log.d("INFO", "Connect() failed with an error.");
              e.printStackTrace();
              continue;
          }
        }
   }
   Log.d("INFO", "Connecting to server on " + ProtCodes.serverIP + ":" + ProtCodes.serverPORT);
};

th.start();
th.join();
```

**Server side:**

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Server* server;
    SOCKADDR_IN sockAddrIn;
    CLIENT_INFO client_info;
    int iResult = 0, number_of_connected_clients = 0, clientLen = sizeof(sockAddrIn);
    std::list<SOCKADDR_IN>* connected_clients; //list of connected clients SOCKADDRS structs (for ip & port)
    t1 = clock();
    try { //validates the PORT argument
        if (atoi(argv[0]) > 1024 && atoi(argv[0]) < 65535)
            server = new Server(atoi(argv[0]));
        else
            server = new Server(DEFAULT_PORT);
    }catch (...){
        server = new Server(5898);
    }

    iResult = listen(server->getSocket(), SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(server->getSocket());
        WSACleanup();
        return TRUE;
    }

    cout << endl << "@Server_log: Connected!" << endl;
    cout << "@Server_log: Launching MySQL server, version: " << string(mysql_get_client_info()) << endl;
    cout << "@Server_log: Server is up running on " << get_ipv4_address() << ":" << ntohs(server->get_server_info().sin_port) << endl;
    cout << "@Server_log: Waiting for requests..." << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************" << endl << endl;
    std::thread server_command(&handle_server_commands, server); //thread for     server commands
    server_command.detach();

    /* Accept a client socket */
    while (number_of_connected_clients < MAX_CONNECTIONS)
    {
        memset(&sockAddrIn, 0, sizeof(sockAddrIn));
        clientLen = sizeof(sockAddrIn);
        ClientSocket = accept(server->getSocket(), (struct sockaddrn*)&sockAddrIn, &clientLen);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            continue;
        }

        /* Print connected client info */
        client_info.ip = inet_ntoa(sockAddrIn.sin_addr);
        client_info.port = ntohs(sockAddrIn.sin_port);
        cout << endl;
        get_current_time();
        cout << "Client connected on " << client_info.ip << " : " << client_info.port << " !" << endl;
        cout << endl << ">> ";
        connected_clients = server->get_connected_clients();
        connected_clients->push_back(sockAddrIn); //push client SOCKADDR     struct into server's clients list
        std::thread a(&(handle_user_requests), ClientSocket, server, client_info); //thread for clients requests handle
        a.detach();
    }

    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    closesocket(server->getSocket());
    WSACleanup();
}
```

**Thanks a lot!**
Idan

Comment: It's normal.192.168.43.60 (port 5898) is only for your local network.You can't visit it if you use GPRS.You can try to use browser to open page on you server with GPRS.

Comment: Of course! I think you misunderstood me :)

When I said that I am connecting to a different Wireless network, I meant with both the app and the server (They are even on the same PC), and then I'm changing the "ProtCodes.ServerIP" variable to the new IPv4 address of the server.

Comment: Do You mean you use a emulator to test ? serverPORT = 5898 .Are you sure your server is working and can be access through other way expect android app?

Comment: I'm using my Galaxy S5 to test my app. Iv'e tried to connect with telnet, and it said that it could not open connection to the host..

Comment: Are you having issues with public networks like coffee shops or aiports?  Those will usually not allow clients to communicate with each other.

Comment: No. I'm having problems with private networks (Friends' networks, etc.) @MilesBudnek

Comment: `new Socket()` creates a socket but does not bind it. That happens when you connect it. You can't reconnect a socket that has failed to connect. You have to close it and use a new socket.